# Defining an array in flash

Tags: c, preprocessor

I need to define different arrays of different sizes and locate them in flash. I know at the compile time the value of the first element, end the limiting value, and let's call is a step value. For example, the first element is 1, the step is 0.9, and the limit 5. So my array should look like

```
const my_arr[] = {1.0, 1.9, 2.8, 3.7, 4.6};
```

Could you please help me to initialize such arrays with the C preprocessor?

PS: This is for a microcontroller, so modifier const will put it in flash, not RAM

Comment: The preprocessor is not sophisticated enough to do this.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Are you asking how to place an array in flash? Or how to define an array in general?

Comment: The problem is not related to the preprocessor. But it is very related to the environment you work in. For example, what compiler are you using? How are you building the application? And how much do you know about *sections* (like data, bss, text etc.) in object and executable files?

Comment: Suggestion write a program that outputs C source code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. it is probably uC. The esiest solution is to write another program in your favourite language generating such a code and add calls to this program to your makefile.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude for most uC platforms const will be enough to place the data into the flash. Some will resuire some magic like AVR PROGMEM or named address spaces. But I do not think that is something OP is asking.

Comment: I did not ask how to put it in flash but how to initialize it prior to putting it there.

Comment: Then as @pmg suggested, make a program (or script) which generates the code.

Comment: Another thing you have to consider, is the space-computation trade-of. How large will the arrays be? How many of these arrays will exist? How much space of the flash memory will it take? If the target system is computationally strong enough and the amount of flash is small,  then perhaps it could do the calculations at run-time and on-demand?

Answer (score 0):

The C preprocessor does not recognize floating-point numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define START 100
#define STEP 90
#define LIMIT 500

int my_arr[] = {
START ,
#if START + STEP < LIMIT
START + STEP ,
#if START + STEP + STEP < LIMIT
START + STEP + STEP ,
#if START + STEP + STEP + STEP < LIMIT
START + STEP + STEP + STEP ,
#if START + STEP + STEP + STEP + STEP < LIMIT
START + STEP + STEP + STEP + STEP ,
#if START + STEP + STEP + STEP + STEP + STEP < LIMIT
START + STEP + STEP + STEP + STEP + STEP ,
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif
};

int main(void) {
    for (int k = 0; k < sizeof my_arr / sizeof *my_arr; k++) {
        printf("%g ", my_arr[k]/100.0);
    }
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 1.9 2.8 3.7 4.6
```

Comment: If I had only one or two arrays like that then I'd type it by hand but there are too many so I need a macro to do so.  Also, sizeof isn't necessary a small number...

Comment: Well ... C preprocessor doesn't do loops ... but see [99 bottles of beer](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/99_bottles_of_beer#A_preprocessor_solution)

Comment: @Submin you need to write another C program or for example python script to generate those initialization.